# AJAX Not posting multi-field form

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, wtforms

I am trying to use a single form that has numerous fields, including FileFields populated from Flask-WTForms. When the form is posted, it does not include any of the data. The form works when the `attachment : form_data,` is not included. (It worked before submitting regular fields, however now I've been trying all day to add file uploading with no success).

My form is as follows:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Material Description</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          {{ form2.description(placeholder='Material Description', class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cost</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          {{ form2.cost(placeholder='Cost', class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quantity</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          {{ form2.quantity(placeholder='Quantity', class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Used</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          {{ form2.used(placeholder='Used', class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Supplier</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          {{ form2.supplier(class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Attachment</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          {{ form2.attachment(class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        {{ form1.hidden_tag() }}             
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                          <button id="materialsButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Materials</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

My endpoint handler:

```
@app.route('/api/submit_materials', methods=['POST'])
    def submit_materials_api():
    form = MaterialsForm()
    form.workorder_id.choices = [(work.id, work.id) for work in Workorder.query.order_by(desc('id'))]
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        workorder_id = form.workorder_id.data
        workorder = Workorder.query.filter_by(id = workorder_id).first_or_404()
        description = form.description.data
        cost = form.cost.data
        quantity = form.quantity.data
        used = form.used.data
        supplier = form.supplier.data
        attachment_filename = secure_filename(form.attachment.file.filename)
        form.attachment.file.save('static/attachments/' + str(workorder_id) + '_' + attachment_filename)
        materials = Materials(description, cost, quantity, used, supplier, attachment_filename)
        workorder.work_order_materials.append(materials)
        db.session.add(materials)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'materials' : materials.description, 'workorder_id' : workorder_id, 'quantity' : quantity})
    else:
        for field, errors in form.errors.items():
            for error in errors:
                error_data = (u"Error in the %s field - %s" % (getattr(form, field).label.text, error))
    return jsonify({'error' : error_data})
```

And what I believe is the culprit, my JS / jQuery:

```
$('#materialsButton').click(function (e) {
                var form_data = new FormData($('#attachment')[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    dataType :"json",
                    url : "/api/submit_materials",
                    data : { 
                            workorder_id : data.workorder_id,
                            description : $('#description').val(),
                            cost : $('#cost').val(),
                            quantity : $('#quantity').val(),
                            used : $('#used').val(),
                            supplier : $('#supplier').val(),
                            attachment : form_data,
                    },
                    contentType : false,
                    cache : false,
                    processData : false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.error) {
                        $("#errorAlert").text(data.error).show();
                        $("#successAlert").hide();
                        }
                     else {
                        $("#successAlert").text(data.quantity + ' of ' + data.materials + ' successfully added to workorder MCI' + data.workorder_id + '. You may submit additional materials or hours below.').show();
                        $("#errorAlert").hide();
                        $("#materialsForm").trigger("reset");
                        $("#hoursForm").fadeIn("slow");
                     }
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
```

To save space this is only a portion of the entire JS script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a formdata object in an ajax request the data field must be the formdata object.

```
            $.ajax({
                ...
                data : form_data,
                ...
            });
```

Also, the formdata constructor takes a form not a field

```
var form_data = new FormData(this.form);
```

This will add all the fields in the form to the formdata object, then use `append()` for the rest of data

```
form_data.append('workorder_id', data.workorder_id);
```

Comment: Oh, okay that makes much more sense. In the case of `workorder_id` the value is passed from the server when the page is rendered, which is why its syntax is different. Every other field takes user input, which is why they're obtained using `$('#description').val(),`. 

When appending, like in your example, what would be the correct syntax when attributing the form data to the right field. Would it be `form_data.append('description', data.description);` or something like `form_data.append('description', ($('#description').val()));` ?

Comment: It would be `form_data.append('description', ($('#description').val()));` but in this case it is unnecessary since when you pass the form to the constructor all the form fields are added(except buttons I think);

Answer (score 0):

you have to serialize the formData before sending to server side. Set a id to your form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="matarialsForm">
```

Then use this jquery.

```
$('#materialsButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();
    var stringData = $('#matarialsForm form').serializeArray();
    $.each(stringData,function(key,input){
            formData.append(input.name,input.value);
    });
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    dataType :"json",
                    url : "/api/submit_materials",
                    data : formData
                    contentType : false,
                    cache : false,
                    processData : false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.error) {
                        $("#errorAlert").text(data.error).show();
                        $("#successAlert").hide();
                        }
                     else {
                        $("#successAlert").text(data.quantity + ' of ' + data.materials + ' successfully added to workorder MCI' + data.workorder_id + '. You may submit additional materials or hours below.').show();
                        $("#errorAlert").hide();
                        $("#materialsForm").trigger("reset");
                        $("#hoursForm").fadeIn("slow");
                     }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: What about the data not in the form. Also that wont work for files.